# Does the Copenhagen interpretation reject probabilistic causation or does it merely reject deterministic causation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, causality

Does the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics reject probabilistic causation or does it merely reject deterministic causation? I read that the Copenhagen interpretation rejects causation, but I am unsure if that includes the rejection of probabilistic causation.

Comment: What would "probabilistic causation" mean in this context? I mean, Copenhagen tells us that we can deduce the probabilities for outcomes using a deterministic rule (the unitary evolution of the state), but we can't deduce the outcome of any given trial (the so-called collapse or selection is treated as unpredictable beyond knowing the PDF).

Comment: Thank you. You indicate that Copenhagen proposes probabilistic causation.